# Want to render or show only few lines from text

Tags: python, flask, text, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using summernote editor for writing blog and sqlalchemy for storing blog data. All functionality working fine. Now on home page, I want to show few lines of each blog which I am not able to do.

I tried few options on views.py however it was throwing pagination error.
I also tried few options with split and slice but no success because of editors html and actual text.

View.py for getting blog post data.

```
blog_posts = BlogPost.query.order_by(BlogPost.date.desc()).paginate(page=page,per_page=5)
```

index.html for rendering blog post data.
This is in for loop

```
<p>{{ post.text|safe }}</p>
```

Data (html + actual text) stored in sqlite table in Text(datatype) column while you read this issue it will only show actual text

```
<p style="margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 0.5em; line-height: inherit; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; letter-spacing: normal; word-spacing: 0px;"><span style="font-size: 10px; font-family: Arial;">?</span><span style="font-family: Arial;">?</span><b><span style="font-family: Arial;">Automation</span></b><span style="font-family: Arial;">&nbsp;is the technology by which a process or procedure is performed with minimal human assistance.</span><sup id="cite_ref-1" class="reference" style="line-height: 1; unicode-bidi: isolate; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 11.2px;"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automation#cite_note-1" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">[1]</span></a></sup><span style="font-family: Arial;">&nbsp;Automation&nbsp;</span><sup id="cite_ref-Rifkin_1995_2-0" class="reference" style="line-height: 1; unicode-bidi: isolate; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 11.2px;"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automation#cite_note-Rifkin_1995-2" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">[2]</span></a></sup><span style="font-family: Arial;">&nbsp;or automatic control is the use of various&nbsp;</span><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_system" title="Control system" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">control systems</span></a><span style="font-family: Arial;">&nbsp;for operating equipment such as machinery, processes in factories, boilers and heat treating ovens, switching on telephone networks, steering and stabilization of ships, aircraft and other applications and vehicles with minimal or reduced human intervention.</span></p><p style="margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 0.5em; line-height: inherit; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; letter-spacing: normal; word-spacing: 0px;"><br></p>
```

Expected Result - I want to show only 3 - 5 lines of text.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#truncate

Comment: Yes                                                                                                       
 post.text|safe - gives me all text,                                          
 post.text|truncate(150) - give me all html tag of editor + data (but html tags are huge)

Comment: Why do you not combine safe and truncate filters

Comment: not working when combining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is show/hide more content button as can be shown in the coding below.

Here I set the character limit to 30 or more. The read more button will appear if the character is more than 30. you can hide content as well.

You can adjust your character limit to suite your choice choice. This is possible using **Jquery/Ajax** and some little css as shown in the code.

Try the code below and ensure that you are connected to internet so as to load the jquery file that will make it to work.

In your case you will need to pass the **class text** to your html paragraph elements
as per below

```
<p class="text">{{ post.text|safe }}</p>
```

**Here is the code sample**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    function breakWords(paragraph, showtext){


        var words = paragraph.split(' ');

        var newText = '';

        for(i=0; i<words.length; i++){


            if(i<= showtext){

                newText += words[i] + ' ';

            }else {

                if (i == (showtext + 1)) newText += '... <span class="fulltext hide">';     

                newText += words[i] + ' ';

                if (words[i+1] == null) newText += '</span><a href="#" class="links"> &raquo; read more</a>';

            }

        }

        return newText;

    }


    $('.text').each(function () {

            $(this).html(breakWords($(this).html(), 10));

            $(this).children('span').hide();


        }).click(function () {


            var fulltext = $(this).children('span.fulltext');
            var links = $(this).children('a.links');


            if (fulltext.hasClass('hide')) {

                fulltext.show(10);
                links.html(' &raquo; hide');        
                fulltext.removeClass('hide');

            } else {

                fulltext.fadeOut(10);
                links.html(' &laquo; read more');           
                fulltext.addClass('hide');

            }

            return false;

        });

});

</script>

<style>


.links{color:#F60; font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="textbox"> 
<p class="text">

The man behind my mystery. It was during the birthday celebration of David frank my first love that I 
met a young businessman who wons my heart over with enticing material gift. catapults me unto of the world promise me.
 a bliss.  
The man behind my mystery. It was during the birthday celebration of David frank my first love that I 
met a young businessman who wons my heart over with enticing material gift. catapults me unto of the world promise me.
 a bliss.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

source [link](http://www.lessoncup.com/2014/03/jquery-text-read-more.html)

Comment: {{ post.text|safe }} I think safe filter not allowing me to read innerhtml or html. Tried various options with no success. Also I would looking  for some option through python or Jinja.